# Android Samsung S21 - Changing region to test localized date formats

Tags: manual-testing, android, internationalization, date

I am attempting to determine if the app code doesn't handle localized date format: Example in USA MM/DD/YYYY in Australia DD/MM/YYYY.

I've change my language to English Australia and my Timezone to Sydney. Is that sufficient to trigger a region change that should be recognized by the code?

I know on iPhone, there is a specific region setting that is separate from language, and that is what I use to test on iPhone.

I also noticed there is a "Country or Region" attached to my Google Play account, which is locked to United States.

Before I report this as a bug, I want to make sure I have properly setup the phone to be in the correct locale.

Does anyone know if I have done everything there is to do?

I googled this and also used ChatGTP-4 and neither gave any other indication of how to change the region as far as I can tell.

Does anyone have experience testing different locales by adjusting the settings on your phone?